# How to get active angular cli environment in karma.conf.js

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have a angular project created with angular cli.

Is there a way to get the current environment value from inside the karma.conf.js

The generated configuration file uses the default environment file.

```
var userEnv = require('./src/environments/environment');
```

I'd like it to use the one set by the ng argument.

```
ng text -e <env-variable>
```

Comment: The CLI has that option with [ng test](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/test). `--environment (aliases: -e)`. Not sure what is does, but it is there!

Comment: Yeah,. i know it's there, I'm wondering how to access the environment variable.

Comment: Something that may help: https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/672